# How to delete audio record from device storage and remove checked recyclerview item. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, audiorecord

I was following a tutorial on Youtube for an audio recorder. I'm now struggling with one thing and that's deleting audio that has been saved.

**Activity that displays saved records**

```
class GalleryActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnItemClickListener {

private lateinit var records: ArrayList<AudioRecord>

private lateinit var mAdapter: Adapter

private lateinit var db: AppDatabase

private var allChecked  = false

private var dirPath = ""

private var filename = ""

private val m_Text = ""

private lateinit var toolbar: MaterialToolbar

private lateinit var searchInput : TextInputEditText

private  lateinit var binding: ActivityGalleryBinding

private lateinit var editBar: View

private lateinit var btnClose: ImageButton

private lateinit var btnSelectAll: ImageButton

private lateinit var btnDelete: ImageButton

private lateinit var btnRename: ImageButton

private lateinit var btnShare: ImageButton

private lateinit var bottomOptions: ConstraintLayout

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityGalleryBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

   // bottomOptions = findViewById(R.id.options_layout)

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarGallery)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    }

    editBar = findViewById(R.id.editBar)
    btnClose= findViewById(R.id.btnClose)
    btnSelectAll= findViewById(R.id.btnSelectAll)
    //btnRename = findViewById(R.id.btnRename)
    //btnDelete= findViewById(R.id.btnDelete)
   //btnShare= findViewById(R.id.btnShare)


    records = ArrayList()


    db = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "audioRecords").build()


    mAdapter = Adapter(records, this)

    binding.recyclerViewGallery.apply {
        adapter = mAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

    }
    fetchAll()

    searchInput = findViewById(R.id.search_input)
    searchInput.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            var query = p0.toString()
            searchDatabase(query)
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

        }

    })

    btnClose.setOnClickListener {
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        editBar.visibility = View.GONE
        // bottomOptions.visibility = View.GONE
        records.map {it.isChecked = false}
        mAdapter.setEditMode(false)
    }

    btnSelectAll.setOnClickListener {
        allChecked = !allChecked
        records.map { it.isChecked = allChecked }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    /* findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btnRename).setOnClickListener{
         renameDialog()

     }

     findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btnDelete).setOnClickListener{
         val mAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@GalleryActivity)
         mAlertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_dialog) //set alertdialog icon
         mAlertDialog.setTitle("Delete") //set alertdialog title
         mAlertDialog.setMessage("Delete audio?") //set alertdialog message
         mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, id ->


             //perform some tasks here
             Toast.makeText(this@GalleryActivity, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }
         mAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, id ->
             //perform som tasks here
             Toast.makeText(this@GalleryActivity, "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }
         mAlertDialog.show()
     }


     findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btnShare).setOnClickListener{
     } */
}

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
private fun deleteRecord(){

    val position: AudioRecord

    if(mAdapter.isEditMode()){
        records.map { it.isChecked = true }
    }


    GlobalScope.launch {

    }

}


private fun renameDialog(){
    val builder: android.app.AlertDialog.Builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Rename audio")
    // Set up the input
    val input = EditText(this)
    // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
    input.hint = "Enter Text"
    input.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
    builder.setView(input)
    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("Save") { _, _ ->
        // Here you get get input text from the Edittext
        var m_Text = input.text.toString()

    }

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") {dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
    builder.show()
}
private fun renameRecord(){

}

@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
private fun searchDatabase(query: String) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        records.clear()
        var queryResult: List<AudioRecord> = db.audioRecordDao().searchDatabase("%$query%")
        records.addAll(queryResult)

        runOnUiThread {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    }
}


@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
private fun fetchAll(){
    GlobalScope.launch {
        records.clear()
        val queryResult: List<AudioRecord> = db.audioRecordDao().getAll()
        records.addAll(queryResult)
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

override fun onItemClickListener(position: Int) {
    val audioRecord = records[position]

    if(mAdapter.isEditMode()){
        records[position].isChecked = !records[position].isChecked
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)

    }else{

        var intent = Intent(this, AudioPlayerActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra("filepath", audioRecord.filePath)
        intent.putExtra("filename", audioRecord.filename)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

override fun onItemLongClickListener(position: Int) {
    mAdapter.setEditMode(true)
    records[position].isChecked = !records[position].isChecked
    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)

    if(mAdapter.isEditMode() && editBar.visibility == View.GONE ){
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)
            editBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            // bottomOptions.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

When a user presses and holds an item in the recyclerview, the item is checked.

[image: This screen here]

I do have a function that allows me to delete the item. I hust don't know how to call it.

**AudioRecordDao**

```
    @Dao
interface AudioRecordDao {

    @Query( "SELECT * FROM audioRecords")
    fun getAll(): List<AudioRecord>

    @Query( "SELECT * FROM audioRecords WHERE filename LIKE :query")
    fun searchDatabase(query: String): List<AudioRecord>

    @Insert
    fun insert(vararg audioRecord: AudioRecord)

    @Delete
    fun delete(audioRecord: AudioRecord)

    @Delete
    fun delete(audioRecords: Array<AudioRecord>)

    @Update
    fun update(audioRecord: AudioRecord)
```

All I want to know is how to delete an item that has been checked and remove it from the devices stroage and from the recyclerview. Which in my case I stored it as `dirPath = "${externalCacheDir?.absolutePath}/"`

**Update**

```
 private fun deleteRecord(){

    var simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyy.MM.DD_hh.mm.ss")
    var date = simpleDateFormat.format(Date())
    filename = "audio_record_$date"

    if(mAdapter.isEditMode()){
        records.map { it.isChecked = true }

        val fullFileLocation = "${externalCacheDir?.absolutePath}/${filename}"
        try { File(fullFileLocation).delete() }catch
            (e: Exception) { Log.e("FileOperationsDelete", e.localizedMessage!!) }
    }

}
```

The changes were only made to this function

Comment: val fullFileLocation = "${fileFolder}/${fileName}"         try {
            File(fullFileLocation).delete()
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("FileOperationsDelete", e.localizedMessage!!)
        } You need the file name

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Please check my question for updated code

Comment: Where do you call deleteRecord() function ? First you need a delete button (view) and call deleteRecord() function. Remove "//" from btnDelete= findViewById(R.id.btnDelete) and create a view on XML with btnDelete id. And call deleteRecord(). Like this;  btnDelete.setOnClickListener { deleteRecord() }

Comment: I that already. I removed "//" put in the code, but nothing happens. I'm not even getting an error in the logcat